# Computing average access time

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

```
A computer has a cache memory and a main memory with the following features:
```

-   Memory cache access time: 4 ns
-   Main memory access time: 80 ns
-   The time needed to load a line in cache is 120 ns.
-   Write-through policy.
If the hit ratio in this computer is 95 % and the 90% of the memory accesses are read operations, what is the average access time?

It seems a bit weird to me since I have read through this site [calculate the effective (average) access time (E AT) of this system](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35884/calculate-the-effective-average-access-time-e-at-of-this-system) but I still do not know how to do it.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a single-level cache, then? That means just two possibilities when accessing: a hit or a miss, with hit rate + miss rate = 100%. It follows that the average is simply the time spent with hits and the time spent with misses, which comes out to:

hit rate * hit time + miss rate * miss time